# Facebook Graph API mutual friends images

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to retrieve users' mutual friends using `context.fields(mutual_friends)`but I need to display images of the friends.  However, I'm only getting back the friends id and name only.  Is it possible to retrieve their images in the same call?

```
 if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(userID)", parameters: ["fields": "context.fields(mutual_friends)"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){

                print("//////Mutual friends")
                print(result!)

            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the image with using this API

https://graph.facebook.com/(friendFacebookId)/picture?type=large

For more info check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/picture)

Comment: Ohh cool, so I guess that would replace the image url...cool!  Thanks